# how to combine 2 arrays in rails such that there are no duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Consider I have 2 arrays,

```
o = ["16", "16", "119"]
d = ["97", "119", "97"]
```

Output that is needed is like this:

```
{16=>[97, 119], 119=>[97]}
```

I tried using `.zip` but it didn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* didn't work? *How* didn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

First thing that comes to mind is this:

```
result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
o.zip(d) { |a, b| result[a] << b }
result #=> {"16"=>["97", "119"], "119"=>["97"]}
```

There probably is a better way though, but this should get you thinking.

Comment: You could use `each_with_object` to get `result` directly, instead of a `nil` from your `zip`. Otherwise, this is probably the most straightforward way.

Comment: The other answers, using `group_by` and `with_index` are far better than this one, but yeah, I was going for super straightforwardness. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could chain [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to group the elements in `d` by the corresponding element in `o`:

```
d.group_by.with_index { |_, i| o[i] }
#=> {"16"=>["97", "119"], "119"=>["97"]}
```

To get integers, you have to add some `to_i` calls:

```
d.map(&:to_i).group_by.with_index { |_, i| o[i].to_i }
#=> {16=>[97, 119], 119=>[97]}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
o.map(&:to_i).zip(d.map(&:to_i)).group_by(&:first).each_value{|a| a.map!(&:last)}
# => {16=>[97, 119], 119=>[97]}
```

Comment: or `group_by(&:first).transform_values(&:last)` with Ruby 2.4